# Is there any rich text editor component for JSF RI?

Tags: jsf

1. I am using JSF RI 1.1. How to add rich text editor component? Is there any rich text editor component available?
2. I am displaying set of images horizontally using the below code. Selected image is stored in database. while showing the images in edit mode, how to highlight the previously selected image?

   ```
   <t:dataList 
       var="item" 
       value="#{occasionBean.messageInfo}"
       layout="simple">
       <h:commandLink action="#{occasionBean.selectedImage}"  >
           <h:graphicImage 
               width="100" height="100" 
               url="#{item.imageSnapUrl}" 
               onclick="return setMsgId(this.id,{item.img_id},'{item.imageUrl}');"
                   id="test">
           </h:graphicImage>
       </h:commandLink>
   </t:dataList>
   ```

Comment: Try asking your two questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

1) [Mojarra Scales](https://web.archive.org/web/20170409013108/https://kenai.com/projects/scales) has a [htmlEditor](https://web.archive.org/web/20170410175806/https://kenai.com/projects/scales/pages/HtmlEditor) component.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kenai.com](https://kenai.com/attachments/wiki_images/scales/editor.png))</sub>

2) Add a `styleClass` conditionally.

```
styleClass="#{item.previouslySelected ? 'selected' : ''}"
```

with this getter

```
public boolean isPreviouslySelected() {
    return previouslySelected;
}
```

and this CSS

```
img.selected {
    border: 2px solid red; /* Use whatever highlight style here. */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dear BalusC. As Pablo Santa Cruz commented i ll ask questions one bye one

Comment: Hi BalusC ur code works fine. but my requirement is little bit different.i failed to explain it clearly. The images are displayed horizontally using <t:dataList>. At first no images are selected if selected it has to be highlighted. If user changes the selection the old has to go normal and new has to be highlighted. while in edit mode we need to highlight the already selected image and they may change in this mode so highlight should change. pls provide some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Richfaces has [editor component](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/editor.jsf?c=editor&tab=usage).