# rich text editor and component to display the text entered vi text editor in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, rich-text-editor

I need to have a rich text editor and a component with which I should be able to display the formatted text. I am using JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some RTF editor bundled with JSF library component (primefaces, richfaces, etc.. )
and I think yuou can display it in a simple div cause the rtf output should use HTML tags and styles  or you can display it in the smae RTF window just in a read only mode

1) use primefaces library version 2.2.1 (cause i think it supports jsf 1.2) , this library got the editor component (you can get some info about it from the documentation [User's Guide 2.2 and 2.2.1](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_2_2.pdf))

2) use a Rich Text Editor like CKEditor in your JSF app, here some ref to how to use Q' + A' [Using CKEditor instead of PrimeFaces Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5988674/using-ckeditor-instead-of-primefaces-editor)

Here another ref with similar Q' + A' about RTF in JSF [Is there any rich text editor component for JSF RI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529351/is-there-any-rich-text-editor-component-for-jsf-ri)

Comment: Daniel thanks for your quick response. Primefaces & Richfaces doesnt support JSF 1.2. For editor we have a couple of options but how to display rich text which was input`ed via rich text editor in JSF?

Comment: you could place the created inside the same editor but in a read only mode without any toolbars ,so it will be like a read only text area, and the latest link I gave ya go some references to RTF editor for JSF 1